# How to convert dwg file to jpeg or gif format using java api or .net library

Tags: java, .net

How can be autocad file (dwg) converted to jpeg or gif file using java api or or .net library. Without using the  convertors

Comment: Convert without using a converter?  Good luck! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look at [Open Design Alliance](http://www.opendesign.com/)